# How to increase the page upload time by compressing the image?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to know how to increase the page upload time by compressing the images on my site, including the exit pop up gif?
Loading time is about 5 seconds.
It was built by WP.
How to fix this issue?
Please, tell me the way.
Thanks.

Comment: questions not clear need more details

Comment: "increase" upload time? or shorten/decrease upload time? how big are the images? If loading time is 5 seconds, what is your expecting time for uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Your image files are likely too large. This is probably because your images have a very high resolution and/or are too large.

If you only need an image to be, say 400 x 500 pixels and your actual image is 1600 x 2000 pixels, you have an unnecessarily large image that will slow down your load time. You can reduce image size right in WordPress using their image editor.

You can also use tools like Photoshop to compress images so that they are smaller files and more web-friendly. Use Photoshop's "save for web" feature and reduce the image quality.

More detailed answers [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51593/how-to-optimize-images-to-improve-pagespeeds-webpage-loading-times).

Comment: Thanks for your help.